# CONFIG_PPP_MPPE=m vs CONFIG_PPP_MPPE=y

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

What is the difference between 'm' and 'y'? I am reading a guide, and the first step is to make sure that my kernel supports PPP and MPPE.

It should be:

```
# cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep G_PPP=
CONFIG_PPP=y
# cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep MPPE
CONFIG_PPP_MPPE=y
```

I get:

```
root@N550JV:~# cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep G_PPP=
CONFIG_PPP=y
root@N550JV:~# cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep MPPE
CONFIG_PPP_MPPE=m
root@N550JV:~#
```

My `uname -r`:

```
3.8.0-39-generic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel features can be compiled in-kernel or compiled as loadable modules. When specifying `y`, the feature will be compiled in kernel. When `m` is specified, the feature will be compiled as a loadable kernel module.

Reference docs:

- PPP: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/
- MPPE: http://mppe-mppc.alphacron.de/

Answer (score 2):

The first option `CONFIG_PPP` is used to enable PPP (point-to-point protocol) support, and the second option `CONFIG_PPP_MPPE` which depends on the first one, is used to enable **specific compression method**. Compression method can differ so it is better to choose `m`(module) instead of `Y`(built-in) so you can load MPPE support when you need it to. If you choose `m` instead of `Y`, could save some bytes from your kernel image size.